# Not enough color using GIF brewery?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

so i'm starting making gifs and i'm really disappointed in the quality of the gif cause the colors are limited 
[image: it looks like this]

it looks like this when it comes out 
[image]

when it should be like this

but i don't have the reduce colors option turned on 
[image]

so how do i keep the original quality?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what software you use, the GIF format is limited to a palette of 256 colors.  Therefore it is unsuitable for photographs.  In other words, the only solution is to use a different format, such as JPEG.  (Or H.264 if you need motion).

Reference: http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/standards/image/gif/index_en.htm

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a normal GIF. Back in 1995 that's what your whole monitor looked like, just not as large. People usually end up looking quite nasty - I wouldn't show the end result to the model.

Try the adaptive palette (and definitely leave dithering on). It looks like you are building an animated GIF so motion will make the results appear better - most video looks rather poor when paused.

If you are not intending to make an animated gif video then you are using the wrong file format - if the example is a still photo then you want jpeg, not gif or png.